# How to implement UIUserNotificationActionBehavior.TextInput from iOS 9 in iOS 8?

Tags: swift, ios8, apple-push-notifications, ios9

I registered `UIMutableUserNotificationAction`:

```
let responseTextAction = UIMutableUserNotificationAction()
responseTextAction.identifier = "text"
responseTextAction.title = "New text"
if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
    responseTextAction.behavior = UIUserNotificationActionBehavior.TextInput
} else {
    // Fallback on earlier versions
}
```

This is screenshot from iOS 9:

[image]

and from iOS 8:

[image]

How can I implement text input for iOS 8 also.

Comment: I supose this is not, but the same thing is working for Messages App. But it may be just private API. Do not you think?

Answer (score 1):

Text Input for Notifications is only available in iOS 9+. Previous versions will default to a standard notification as you have seen.